# PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Server SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, metadata, sql-variant-property

Does PostgreSQL have an equivalent function for determining column metadata?

Reference: [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx)

[pg_typeof()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) appears to be close, but it does not show the precision and scale. Looking up the type in [pg_type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-type.html) only shows the generic type info, not the column specific, e.g. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/032b5/3/0).

Answer (score 3):

The fact that `pg_typeof` doesn't show the typmod is frustrating.

To get the fully qualified type you can query the system catalogs. Let's look at how `psql` does it using `psql -E`:

```
$ psql -E regress
psql (9.2.1)
Type "help" for help.

regress=> CREATE TABLE typmodtest ( a numeric(16,2), b varchar(32) );
CREATE TABLE
regress=> \d typmodtest

... tons of information printed, including this query which produces the information we want:

SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
  a.attnotnull, a.attnum,
  (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation c, pg_catalog.pg_type t
   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation) AS attcollation,
  NULL AS indexdef,
  NULL AS attfdwoptions
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = '24641' AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

This query can clearly be trimmed if you're not interested in the field collation, `NOT NULL` status, etc. We can also change the `attrelid` filter from an oid to a regclass filter:

```
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = 'typmodtest'::regclass 
  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

producing:

```
 attname |      format_type      
---------+-----------------------
 a       | numeric(16,2)
 b       | character varying(32)
```

This will only work on relations. I'm not aware of a reliable, generic way to get the typmod-qualified type for any result set, and it's a serious irritation. Among other things it makes it hard for the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to be compliant.

Answer (score 2):

Since PostgreSQL 9.2, there is also [`collation for (any)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get the collation (if any) - which is one of the 6 properties you can retrieve with `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` in SQL Server.
Works universally, not just for table columns.

You'll find more on [`format_type()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) at the same page of the manual.
[@Craig demonstrated](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28160/3684) how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
select column_name, DATA_TYPE,NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='YourTable'
```

?

Answer (score 0):

## PostgreSQL 11 with `psql`

I believe now you can just use `\gdesc`

```
SELECT
    NULL AS zero,
    1 AS one,
    2.0 AS two,
    'three' AS three,
    $1 AS four,
    sin($2) as five,
    'foo'::varchar(4) as six,
    CURRENT_DATE AS now
\gdesc
 Column |         Type         
--------+----------------------
 zero   | text
 one    | integer
 two    | numeric
 three  | text
 four   | text
 five   | double precision
 six    | character varying(4)  -- XXX: notice the (4)
 now    | date
(8 rows)
```

Patch: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=49ca462eb165dea297f1f110e8eac064308e9d51