# MySQL metadata function to get projected column type in query?

Tags: mysql, metadata

Is it possible to get the field type from a MySQL **query**, in the same way you can get it from a table with the `SHOW COLUMNS` command? Such as from a derived table,

```
SELECT x -- presumedMetaFn(x) -- returns "int"
FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS x
  UNION SELECT 2
) AS t;
```

Given the above query, is there a function or something that I can use to get the type of x? PostgreSQL makes this available with the [System Information Functions `pg_typeof`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

```
SELECT x, pg_typeof(x)
FROM ( VALUES (1),(2) ) AS t(x);
 x | pg_typeof 
---+-----------
 1 | integer
 2 | integer
(2 rows)
```

**I am not looking for metadata on a table, but from the result of query.** [With `psql` on PostgreSQL 11+, this is also possible by running `\gdesc` after the query.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/211577/2639)

Comment: I would highly suggest you choose this answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62262/2639 (which is the only way to do it within the official client) or my own https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203927/2639 (which addresses the C API). The chosen answer, addressing only the Perl bindings from the user's perspective seems off topic here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Within MySQL, you can get this information by creating a temporary table, then using `DESCRIBE` on that temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp`
SELECT ...
FROM ...
LIMIT 0;

DESCRIBE `temp`;
```

We cannot just use `DESCRIBE` on the original table because the column we want to know the type of is a calculated column, not something being directly pulled from a table.  Likewise, we cannot use `DESCRIBE` directly on the query, because `DESCRIBE` can only be used on tables.  Creating a temporary table solves both of those problems.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a comparable way to hand a query to MySQL and ask it to return a resultset containing the names and attributes of the columns that your query will return when it is executed.

However, the library you're using to access MySQL probably has such a mechanism that your code could use... because on the wire, MySQL does return this information to clients with every executed query.

By way of example, the [DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/DBD-mysql-2.9003/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) library in Perl returns arrays of column names and data types.

An executed statement handle returns an array of the column names in @{$sth->{NAME}} and array of the column data types in @{$sth->{mysql_type_name}}.  It gets these from functions provided by the MySQL C API, which (as far as I know) is the same underlying code used by a lot of different languages for their MySQL libraries... so I would expect similar structures to be exposed in other environments.

Comment: Perl is typing into the [MySQL C API through XS](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203927/2639)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this data is available through the [C API and documented in *C API Prepared Statement Type Codes*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html) but that the server has **no such ability to provide it to the end user,**

> The buffer_type member of `MYSQL_BIND` structures indicates the data type of the C language variable bound to a statement parameter **or result set column.** For input, `buffer_type` indicates the type of the variable containing the value to be sent to the server. **For output, it indicates the type of the variable into which a value received from the server should be stored.**

For [a table of the SQL types, and the corresponding `buffer_type` value see this chart.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/c-api-prepared-statement-type-codes.html)

The only work around is to [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) ... DESCRIBE`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/62262/2639)

Answer (score -1):

The question, as I read it is about getting details on the columns in a resultset, as opposed to the columns of database tables.

If you are using PHP, there are built-in functions for accessing databases with MYSQLI and PDO which can give you detailed information (data type and so forth) about the columns in a query result (as opposed to the columns of the original tables).

For details about these methods see the PHP documentation:

- [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)
- [mysqli_result::fetch_field_direct](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php)