# Case insensitive column names in a postgresql trigger function

Tags: postgresql, trigger, plpgsql, case-sensitive

I have a trigger function in PostgreSQL 12 which executes something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "my_latlon_function"()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    latcolumn:= (
        SELECT column_name
          FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
           AND table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME
           AND column_name ~* '.*lat.*'
    );
    loncolumn := (
        SELECT column_name
          FROM information_schema.columns
         WHERE table_schema = TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
           AND table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME
           AND column_name ~* '.*lon.*'
    );
    EXECUTE 'select $1.' || loncolumn USING NEW INTO lon;
    EXECUTE 'select $1.' || latcolumn USING NEW INTO lat;

    -- do much stuff

    RETURN NEW;

END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The problem is, the `lat` and `lon` columns have capital letters in their name, e.g. `myLatitude` and `myLongitude`. The trigger function is able to retrieve these names, that's no problem.

The problem lies in the two `EXECUTE` statements where it seems that the column names become lower-cased as stated by this error (in the underlying QUERY when the trigger is fired):

```
ERROR:  column "mylongitude" not found in data type gpspoints
LINE 1: select $1.myLongitude
               ^
QUERY:  select $1.myLongitude
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_latlon_function() line 24 at EXECUTE
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "mylongitude" not found in data type gpspoints
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function my_latlon_function() line 24 at EXECUTE
```

I know that PostgreSQL does need to enclose column names which have capital letters in their name into double quotes. Hence, I have tried to set double quotes in the two EXECUTE statements such as this:

```
    EXECUTE 'select $1.' || "loncolumn" USING NEW INTO lon;
    EXECUTE 'select $1.' || "latcolumn" USING NEW INTO lat;
```

But the error stays exactly the same.

If possible, how can I handle CamelCase column names in a PostgreSQL trigger function?

If not not, why?

Comment: You really would save yourself a lot of trouble in future by renaming the columns to lowercase. One time pain to avoid all of this jumping-through-hoops ever again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` with the `%I` placeholder for identifiers:

```
EXECUTE format('select $1.%I', latcolumn) USING NEW INTO lat;
```

Answer (score 2):

Double-quote identifiers automatically where needed with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) (like Laurenz demonstrates), or [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

Also, your trigger function can be more efficient like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_latlon_function()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _latcol text;
   _loncol text;
   _lat numeric;
   _lon numeric;
BEGIN
   SELECT quote_ident(a.attname) INTO _latcol  -- properly quoted!
   FROM   pg_attribute a
   WHERE  a.attrelid = TG_RELID
   AND    a.attname ~* 'lat'
   AND    a.attnum > 0
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped;

   SELECT quote_ident(a.attname) INTO _loncol
   FROM   pg_attribute a
   WHERE  a.attrelid = TG_RELID
   AND    a.attname ~* 'lon'
   AND    a.attnum > 0
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped;
   
   EXECUTE concat('SELECT $1.', _latcol, ', $1.', _loncol)
   USING  NEW
   INTO   _lat, _lon;

   RAISE NOTICE '% / %', _lat, _lon;  -- debug output

   -- do much stuff

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b03b08e47446e5b164939164e305e1be)*

(This is assuming column names always match unambiguously!?)

Demonstrating `quote_ident()`. With column names already quoted properly, we can simply `concat()` later.

The catalog table `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` is notably faster than `information_schema.columns`. Compare the output of these two commands to understand why:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns;
```

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute;
```

See:

- [Query to return output column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/query-to-return-output-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)
- [How do I list all columns for a specified table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-do-i-list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table/22420#22420)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

In this particular case, we can also conveniently use [`TG_RELID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) instead of `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`.

Also, individual assignments are comparatively expensive in PL/pgSQL. Try to keep their number low.

While the difference in performance is still small, this trigger function is called once per inserted row. Adds up for big inserts ...

Aside, `col ~* 'lon'` is exactly equivalent to `col ~* '.*lon.*'`.