# Unable to use ::regclass on information_schema table_name

Tags: postgresql

Attempting to run a simply query:

```
SELECT t.table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables AS t
    JOIN pg_index i
      ON i.indrelid = t.table_name::regclass
```

I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "account" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

From my understanding I need to cast the t.table_name with ::regclass in order to compare against indrelid. I'm assuming it's not working because the table is in another schema other than the public schema. How do I run this query to include tables in schemas other than the public schema?

db structure:

```
schema: public
tables: n/a

schema: core
tables: account, collection
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve my problem by changing my query to:

```
SELECT t.table_name
    FROM information_schema.tables AS t
    JOIN pg_index i
      ON i.indrelid = (quote_ident(t.table_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(t.table_name))::regclass
```

Using the quote_ident() to concat both parts of the schema and table name together before casting ::regclass works the same as:

```
'schema_name.table_name'::regclass
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is that reported names are case-sensitive, so some require double-quoting, and `quote_ident()` or `format()` take care of that.

Depending on what your query is supposed to do *exactly*, you might simply:

```
SELECT indrelid::regclass FROM pg_index;
```

To get the table name only, even when `search_path` does not cover it. And applying the same filters as `information_schema.tables` - except access privileges:

```
SELECT c.relname
FROM   pg_index i 
JOIN   pg_class c ON c.oid = i.indrelid
WHERE  c.relkind = ANY ('{r,v,f,p}'::"char"[])
AND    NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(c.relnamespace)
```

Including access privileges:

```
SELECT c.relname
FROM   pg_index i 
JOIN   pg_class c ON c.oid = i.indrelid
WHERE  c.relkind = ANY ('{r,v,f,p}'::"char"[])
AND    NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(c.relnamespace)
AND   (pg_has_role(c.relowner, 'USAGE'::text)
    OR has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER')
    OR has_any_column_privilege(c.oid, 'SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES'))
```

Why bother? 3 - 100 x as fast. And more versatile. See:

- [Get column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/get-column-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view/75124#75124)
- [What is faster: pg_catalog or information_schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302587/what-is-faster-pg-catalog-or-information-schema/302589#302589)